# Stepper back button does not change state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement a stepper. If I click on next everything works. But if I then click back, the state does not change directly. Only after several clicks.

**PS: The whole thing just doesn't work in Chrome. Everything works as it should in Edge**

```
const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);

const handleBack = () => {
  if (activeStep !== 1) {
    setActiveStep((prev) => prev - 1);
  }
};

const handleNext = () => {
  setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
}

return(
 <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", pt: 2 }}>
          <Button
            color="inherit"
            onClick={handleBack}
            sx={{ mr: 1, display: activeStep > 1 ? "block" : "none" }}
          >
            back
          </Button>
          <Box sx={{ flex: "1 1 auto" }} />
          <Button onClick={handleNext}>
            {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "send" : "next"}
          </Button>
 </Box>
)
```

Comment: `if (activeStep !== 1) { setActiveStep(` Well yes, what else were you expecting? Your current code only steps back if the active step isn't 1. If you increment the step to 1, then you won't be able to go back from 1. You probably meant to use 0 instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Hey I added something to my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `activeStep` state is updated to the value `1` the previous button will no longer decrement the active step value. I would suggest just setting the `activeStep` state to the maximum of `activeStep - 1` and `0`. Use a functional state update when both incrementing and decrementing the `activeStep` state.

Example:

```
const handleBack = () => {
  setActiveStep(step => Math.maximum(0, step - 1));
};

const handleNext = () => {
  setActiveStep(step => Math.minimum(steps.length - 1, step + 1));
}
```

You could take the UI a step further and disable the next/previous buttons when the active step is the last/first step.

```
return (
  <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", pt: 2 }}>
    <Button
      color="inherit"
      disabled={activeStep === 0}
      onClick={handleBack}
      sx={{ mr: 1, display: activeStep > 1 ? "block" : "none" }}
    >
      back
    </Button>
    <Box sx={{ flex: "1 1 auto" }} />
    <Button
      disabled={activeStep === steps.length - 1}
      onClick={handleNext}
    >
      {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "send" : "next"}
    </Button>
 </Box>
)
```